# How to make a table wide in a twocolumn-mode document?

Tags: tables, page-breaking, two-column

How could I make a table wide (like using table*) in a twocolumn-mode document, that can break a page?

Below the expected result (made in any ordinary text editor).

Page 1
[image: Expected long table exhibition- Page 1]

Page 2
[image: Expected long table exhibition- Page 2]

**UPDATE**

By following a suggestion of using multicols and longtable, this is the achieved output. In the first page it seems ok, but after break, the multicol environment is not followed accordingly.

```
\documentclass[final,5p,times,twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcount\n
\n=0
\def\tablebody{}
\makeatletter
\loop\ifnum\n<50
    \advance\n by1
    \protected@edef\tablebody{\tablebody
            \textbf{\number\n.}& shortText & longlonglonglonglong text
            longlonglonglonglong text
            \tabularnewline
    }
\repeat
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \lipsum[1-10]

    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \end{multicols}

    \begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|}
    \caption[Triple columns]{Triple columns.}\\
    \hline 
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Time (s)}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Triple chosen}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Other feasible triples}} \\ 
    \hline
    \endfirsthead

        \multicolumn{3}{c}%
        {{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
    \hline 
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Time (s)}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Triple chosen}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Other feasible triples}} \\ 
    \hline 
    \endhead

    \hline 
        \multicolumn{3}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\ 
    \hline
    \endfoot

    \hline \hline
    \endlastfoot

    \tablebody

    \end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Page 1
[image: Page 1- update]

Page 2
[image: Page 2- update]

Page 3
[image: Page 3- update]

Comment: `\begin{multicols}{2}.....\end{multicols} \begin{longtable}{ccc}....`

Comment: What @David suggests is very likely the only way to go. But, wouldn't `\begin{table*}[t]YOUR WIDE TABLE\end{table*}` be enough, given you drop the requirement to split it over pages?

Comment: David's suggestion is not working fine (check out the UPDATE above). I guess `table*` environment doesn't work properly with multiple pages.

Comment: You have not put the two column material inside the multicols so it is unlikely to work! You should use multicols _instead_ of `[twocolumn]`

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcount\n
\n=0
\def\tablebody{}
\makeatletter
\loop\ifnum\n<50
    \advance\n by1
    \protected@edef\tablebody{\tablebody
            \textbf{\number\n.}& shortText & longlonglonglonglong text
            longlonglonglonglong text
            \tabularnewline
n    }
\repeat
\makeatother

\begin{document}

    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \lipsum[1-7]
    \end{multicols}

\footnotesize
    \begin{longtable}{|l|l|l|}
    \caption[Triple columns]{Triple columns.}\\    
    \hline 
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Time (s)}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Triple chosen}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Other feasible triples}} \\ 
    \hline
    \endfirsthead

        \multicolumn{3}{c}%
        {{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\
    \hline 
        \multicolumn{1}{|c|}{\textbf{Time (s)}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Triple chosen}} & \multicolumn{1}{c|}{\textbf{Other feasible triples}} \\ 
    \hline 
    \endhead

    \hline 
        \multicolumn{3}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\ 
    \hline
    \endfoot

    \hline \hline
    \endlastfoot

    \tablebody

    \end{longtable}

\normalsize
    \begin{multicols}{2}
    \lipsum[1-10]
    \end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is almost ok. The twocolumn-mode should be stated as a document class option, instead of within the `\begin{multicols}...\end{multicols}` tags.

Comment: @IvanMachado No that's the point. If you use `twocolumn` you can only switch between one and two column by using `\onecolumn` and `\twocolumn` which force a page break. `multicols` uses a different mechanism specifically to allow what you show, changing the number of columns mid page.

Comment: So, let me state my point... what I need/want is an impossible thing to handle without this multicols, isn't it? My text is too long, and I have to strictly follow the journal latex class (we must use a single latex file, instead of "modularizing" things in separate files). There is only a single table I'm facing this problem, and I'm not a 100% sure I can change the global class option to `onecolumn` without loss of, e.g., text alignment, like the column width, etc.

Comment: @IvanMachado so you need to use `\onecolumn\begin{longtable}....\end{lontable}\twocolumn`  but the table will start on a new page in that case. Or split it by hand and use two `table*` environments.

Comment: Yep. I've just tried doing this other way, but I noticed the forced page break. Anyway, I guess I'm going to use split the table by hand, with `table*` env. Thanks for your support!