# Right the the text just after table

Tags: page-breaking, longtable, two-column

i have a two column article with a one column `longtable` and i want to move the text after this table just below the table without page break.

[image]

My Code

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{blindtext,longtable}

\begin{document}
\section{TwoColumnpage}
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext
\blindtext

\begin{table}[h]

\centering
\label{Table:District}
    \begin{tabular}{l|c}

    Col1 & COl2 \\
        \hline
        01 &  6 \\
        02 & 6 \\
        03 & 6 \\
        04 & 6 \\
        05 & 6 \\
        06 & 6 \\
        07 &  6 \\
        08 & 6 \\
        09 & 6 \\
        10 &  6 \\
        13 & 6 \\
        14 & 6 \\
    \end{tabular}


\end{table}

\begin{onecolumn}

\begin{longtable}[c]{lllllllll}
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
\endfirsthead
%
\endhead
%
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
1 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 2 & 1 \\
 &  &  &  &  &  &  &  & 
\end{longtable}
\end{onecolumn} 



\twocolumn

how i can move this text to after table without newpage
\blindtext

\end{document}
```

Comment: Related: [How to make a table wide in a twocolumn-mode document?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/141524/134144)

Comment: you could do that easily if you use multicol package, not with a standard two column option

Comment: the content of this question makes sense, but the title doesn't, and i'm not sure how to fix it.  but i'm sure you can make it better.